# clever at Physics or clever in Physics

Tags: word-choice

> This student is clever at Physics.
>
> This student is clever in Physics.

I want to know whether I can use the word "clever" in this sentence and suitable preposition, **in** or **at**?

Comment: Probably neither.  If I had to use one or the other I would say *clever at* ... but "clever" isn't really a word I'd use in this context.  Despite the definitions it's more associated with someone who comes up with unusual, unexpected, or inventive ways to solve puzzles. So saying "clever at Physics" seems subtly off.  Someone might find clever *solutions* to Physics problems because they are *good at* Physics, or even *brilliant at* Physics, though.

Answer (score 2):

I doubted such usage, because the usual example is **be good at**, so I looked it up in the dictionary and saw the following (dictionary.cambridge.org)

**Clever**

having or showing the ability to learn and understand things quickly and easily:

> **uk Fiona is very clever at physics**.

​
skilful:

> **My mother is very clever with her hands**.

*At* is used to denote a sphere,subject, activity.  *In* is not used in this meaning. Compare :He was good in that film. (in a certain work)